# how to send page loaded signal to website in c# .net web browser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, ui-automation

I am trying to automate login process of my university email. However before logging in, i have to wait for page to load completely (which is a very heavy one and often takes long time) after which it starts timer of 10 seconds to see news section and then login captcha pops up. what i want is to be able to send "document loading completed" signal to the website to start timer earlier. Is it possible to send a "fake" signal to the website using c# web browser? i may also use gecko if suggested...

Answer (score 0):

There may be some javascript/jquery you can run to skip the timer on the browser. I would suggest taking a look into the javascript around the timer and seeing a way to bypass it.

Without any actual code, I can't really help besides that.